# PHP Functions - Maximum number of arguments

Tags: php

In PHP, when defining a function what is the maximum number of arguments that you can create?  This isn't something I am doing, just a question that popped up when discussing it with a colleague :)

Would this be purely down a memory limitation? effectively unlimited?

Comment: Why don't you test? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049673/php-functions-maximum-number-of-arguments/8049856#8049856

Comment: I'm very grateful he didn't, but asked instead. You see, this way we don't all have to, either. SO has just served the community wonderfully again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Arguments to a function are pushed on a stack, after which the function is called which in turn reads the stack and uses those values as parameters.

So as long as the stack isn't full, you can keep adding parameters, but it'll depend on the situation, and at design-time you won't know the stack size.

But I really hope this is pure a technical discussion and you don't need it IRL. ;-)

Comment: haha, no no, as I mentioned this isn't IRL - purely technical ramblings :-)

Answer (score 16):

There is no limit. And you can always use `func_get_args()`, `func_get_arg()` and `func_num_args()` to avoid writing all the arguments in the function definition.

Answer (score 7):

> when defining a function what is the maximum number of arguments that you can create?

I'm not aware of specific limit in the number of arguments as a fixed number. A quick test revealed that I had no problems to define a function with 255 555 arguments. It does take some time to define the function and to execute it. However, it works.

As the number was raised, I was running into a memory limit which could be string limit. You might want to improve the test-case, use a buffer and save the file to disk sequentially and include it then:

```
$count = 255555;

$code = 'function test(%s) {return 1;}; return test();';

$params = ltrim(implode('=0, $p', range(0, $count)), '0, =').'=0';

echo eval(sprintf($code, $params));
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know what are the limits, but either way, if you create a function with too many arguments your code will not be so easy to read it. In case you like to add many function arguments you can do something like that:

```
$option = array(
    'arg_1' => 'value',
    'arg_2' => 'value',
    ....
    'arg_x' => 'value'
);

function function_name($args = "")
{
    $defaults = array(
        'arg_1' => 'default_value',
        'arg_2' => 'default_value'
        ....
        'arg_x' => 'default_value'
    );

    $arguments = array_merge($defaults, (array)$args);
    extract($arguments);

    echo $arg_1;
    echo $arg_x;
}
```