# How much is the limitation of argument length in a function in PHP?

Tags: php, function

How much is the limitation of argument length is passed to a function in PHP?

Is this possible to send output of a mysql query with more than 2000 records as an array to a function to render the result as a grid?

Comment: I don't believe there is a specific maximum arg list length, but sure you can send a single array with thousands of rows.

Comment: Have you tried to send it?

Comment: An array with 2000 records is different than 2000 arguments

Comment: There is technically no limit on the number of arguments passed to a function, as each one will be pushed onto the stack.  Of course you would run out of stack space with too many of them but this is likely to be an astronomical number. Records should be passed\returned as an array though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Functions - Maximum number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049673/php-functions-maximum-number-of-arguments)

Comment: If your really worried about having huge datasets then you could look into using a [generator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php)

Comment: I think he's not asking about the **number of** arguments but the max size of **a single** argument (in terms of memory consumption etc.)

Comment: The only limit is how much memory you have allocated to PHP and whether you are running x86 or x64.

Answer (score 2):

In theory there are no limitations on parameter size in PHP I can think of. And even if there are any you can probably just increase their limit in the `php.ini`

However here's an idea on how to make your code more efficient:
In PHP it is possible to pass arguments [by reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference) rather than by value. This means your function only gets told where to find the array instead of copying the whole thing over just to pass it into a function. Implications of that are, that if you modify the array from inside the function those changes will also get visible on the outside since you're working on the same exact array. (Think of it as a share.)

Comment: Probably not necessary to pass by reference as PHP does "copy on write". So, even if you don't pass the array by reference, it won't make a copy of the array unless it needs to (only if you change the data).